# Client Credential Flow without Admin login

Tags: azure, certificate, office365

Following [these](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/) instructions on implementing client credential flow, using [this](https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp) sample repo to test on, I got a running version of an app using client credential flow that can read email, calendar, contacts.

However I need to sign in with my O365 tenant admin every time I run it and grant access to the application to read emails, calendar, etc.

Isn't the whole point of Client Credential Flow (app-only) that I shouldn't need to enter any credentials to read data, since I've created a certificate that connects my AAD-app with my web-app.

The only thing I can think of is that I have to sign in with the admin just once to set it up properly, but then it makes no sense that I get prompted to login as admin every time I run the application (running on localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run admin consent once, then that should give your app the access it needs with just its client id and secret. Now this only matters to application permissions obviously, if you are using delegated permissions, those always require a logged in user.

To give admin consent, you will need to hit a URL like this in Azure AD:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your-client-id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.company.com%2Fazure-redirect%2F&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent

Replace your-client-id with your app's client id, and the redirect URI with a reply URL registered for your app (URL-encoded of course). It should prompt you with something like "Do you want to give app AppName the following permissions? No one else in the organization will be asked." You can also replace common with your tenant id or domain name.

You can use the [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/) to check if the consent was passed successfully. Check *servicePrincipals*, find your app, and then check *oauth2PermissionGrants* and find the objects with your service principal's id. That will tell you what permissions have been granted and on what resources (the Graph API etc.)

Comment: How do I make sure that the person accessing the app is actually in the organization? Or I guess I dont, that is the point? Just feels quite unsafe ^^

Comment: If your app is single-tenant, only users from that Azure AD can sign in. But now you gave your app permissions to do things without user identity. Then if you have some parts of your application that use those app-only permissions, you have to make sure the authorization is set up correctly.